# Heroku failed to deploy detecting sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sqlite

I do not have `sqlite` installed I am using `pg` here is my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem 'geoip'
gem 'ziptastic'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.7.2'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'guard'      
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'meta_request'
end
```

I deleted `gemfile.lock` and ran bundle. For some reason `sqlite3 (1.3.9)` is appearing in my `gemfile.lock`...

According to Heroku  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler

> Running bundle install also generates a Gemfile.lock file, which
>   should be added to your git repository. Gemfile.lock ensures that your
>   deployed versions of gems on Heroku match the version installed
>   locally on your development machine.

Why is `gemfile.lock` showings `sqlite3` if it's not in my Gemfile and how do I fix this? Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was the `gem ziptastic` has a sqlite3 dependency which is why my `gemfile.lock` was including `sqlite3`. If you're having a similar issue I suggest you check the dependencies of each gem.

Comment: But then what ? You remove all gem that had sqlite dependencies ? Is there a way to make it ok with heroku ?